# Java debuging decompiled classes without line number attributes

Tags: java, debugging, decompiling

Is there any way to debug a 3rd party Java code (library) which, as I believe, was compiled without line number attributes? I attach a debugger to this class (decompiled in Eclipse using JadClipse) and I can set breakpoints on method entries, but cannot step through code line by line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a Java application without access to the source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843096/how-to-debug-a-java-application-without-access-to-the-source-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can re-compile the decompiled code and debug that instead of the "real" jar?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Thilo, but this is not a solution for me as I am debugging an applet, which is deployed on a remote server. Technically I think I could recompile and "inject" it, but I am looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: As this is the only solution provided (despite the fact, that I was looking for some cleaner way to do this), I accept it. Thank you, Thilo.